# how to register a keystore extension in substrate benchmarking?

Tags: rust, substrate

I'm writing benchmark for a pallet, in which I need to generate key pairs as input. However with `--features runtime-benchmarking`, I seems not able to use `full-crypto` and `sp_core::Pair`.
So the only way I found is to use `RuntimeAppPublic::generate_pair`, but it needs a `keystore` registered for the `ext`. But with `benchmark!` macro I wasn't able to do this.

So are there any suggestions? Either on generating keypairs without std or registering a keystore extension within the `benchmark!` framework.

Edit: I found something may be helpful in the doc.

````rust
/// You can construct benchmark by using the `impl_benchmark_test_suite` macro or
/// by manually implementing them like so:
///
/// ```ignore
/// #[test]
/// fn test_benchmarks() {
///   new_test_ext().execute_with(|| {
///     assert_ok!(Pallet::<Test>::test_benchmark_dummy());
///     ...
///   });
/// }
/// ```
````

From this doc, I think we can manipulate the `test_ext` easily for the test. But there are no information about the `bench_xxx` functions. As far as I can see in the `cargo expand` file, it maybe a bit different for benchmark.

Answer (score 0):

It's about genesis config, closing.